# How to check for corrupt mp3 files using ffmpeg in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, mp3

Using the 'ffmpeg-static' npm package I managed to integrate ffmpeg in my node application, and run the [example][1]https://github.com/eugeneware/ffmpeg-static/blob/dce6d42ba772a5769df8181e704772db4456ef16/example.js code.

The gist of the code is:

```
import pathToFfmpeg from "ffmpeg-static";
import shell from 'any-shell-escape';
import { exec } from "child_process";

 function runFfmpeg(src, dest) {
  //where src is a existing mp3 file in a folder and dest is the destination folder
  const script = shell([
    pathToFfmpeg,
    '-y', '-v', 'error',
    '-i', resolve(process.cwd(), src),
    '-acodec', 'mp3',
    '-format', 'mp3',
    resolve(process.cwd(), dest),
  ]);

  exec(script);
}
```

This works and this decodes and encodes the source file into mp3 and saves it in the dest folder.

However, when I try what should be the simplest ffmpeg terminal command, such as `ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -hide_banner` it does not work. I have tried

```
function runFfmpeg(src, dest) {
  const script = shell([
    pathToFfmpeg,
    '-i', resolve(process.cwd(), src), '-hide_banner'
  ]);

  const fileInfo = exec(script);
  return fileInfo;
```

In the end, where I want to get to is being able to use my **runFfmpeg** function to check if an mp3 file has any missing or corrupted frames, using a terminal command that I found in the interwebs:
`ffmpeg -v error -i video.ext -f null`

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that you're not specifying the output file. FFmpeg requires output file to be defined even if a null format is used. You can use output pipe `-` (check your interweb source again, I bet it's there):

```
ffmpeg -v error -i video.ext -f null -
```

Now, do you actually need to know what went wrong? (which requires shifting through the log file.)

If you only care to have a simple yes/no question, you can instead run:

```
ffmpeg -xerror -i video.ext -f null -
```

and check the return code. If non-zero, FFmpeg couldn't process all the frames. Because it exits immediately, it'll save your runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a further question. Would an error mean that the file does not play? Unfortunately I can't test this as all the files I've tested on so far seem to be ok and I don't know how to corrupt an mp3 file intentionally to test this

Comment: Hmmm, I wouldn't know to be honest. We are at the mercy of mp3 decoder to report the error or not. If it does not report corrupted frame as an error back to FFmpeg, FFmpeg wouldn't know to shut down. If you run it with `-v error` does it indicate any sign of corruption?